# PHP - Take Images from .txt

Tags: php, text, line

In my .txt there is numbers in every line. It's like

```
23
4325
435346
34535345345345345
```

So my question is, how can I get every line? I want to make

```
<img src="/files/$txtline1$.png"></img>
<img src="/files/$txtline2$.png"></img>
etc...
```

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [file](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_file.asp) function.

```
$txtline = file("test.txt");
```

This way, `$txtline` will be an array containing each line of `test.txt`, such that `$txtline[0]` will be the first line, `$txtline[1]` will be the second, etc.

---

So in your scenario,

```
<img src="/files/<?php echo $txtline[0] ?>.png"></img>
<img src="/files/<?php echo $txtline[1] ?>.png"></img>
etc...
```

Or if you are looking to loop it, from the start of txt file to the end,

```
<?php
    for($i = 0; $i < count($txtline); $i++) {
        echo '<img src="/files/'.'$txtline[$i]'.'.png"></img>'
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `file_get_contents`

```
$data = explode("\n", file_get_contents('filename.txt'));
```

This way you get all data of your textfile with \n separated in data array. By using `for loop` you can extract it in your data

```
for ($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++)  
{
    echo "<img src='/files/$data[$i].png'></img>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one...

```
    <?Php
    $text = file('text.txt');
    foreach($text as $name)
    { ?>
   <img src="/files/<?php echo $name ?>.png"></img>
    <?php } ?>
```

but be sure with your image extensions....

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
<?php
$file=fopen("file.txt","r");
while(!feof($file)){
    echo "<img src='".fgets($file).".png'></img><br/>";
}
fclose($file);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use file_get_contents to get data

explode to get individual row and

chr(10) as "\n" for line break

```
<?php

$redis_data =  explode( chr(10), file_get_contents("test12.txt"));
foreach ($redis_data as $data) { 

    if(!empty($data) ) {
        echo "<img src='/files/$data.png'></img> <br/>";
    }

}

?>
```